# Simple use for synchronization in Java

Tags: java, synchronization, runnable, implements, java-threads

Hmm, I wrote a program for Banking system using synchronization. I ran in into some error, the output doesn't calculate withdraw amount correctly, and the whole output gets printed not in the order for threads... Please, help with suggestions. Thank you.

Account.java

```
public class Account {

    private double balance = 0;

    public Account(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

DepositThread.java

```
public class DepositThread implements Runnable {

    private Account account;
    private double amount;

    public DepositThread(Account account, double amount) {
        // Set the account & balance
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) throws InterruptedException {
        double bal = account.getBalance();
        if (amount <= 0) {
            wait();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't not deposit!");
        }

        bal += amount;
        account.setBalance(bal);
        System.out.println("Deposit " + amount + " new balance in thread number " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + " balance is " + bal);
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        // make a deposit
        try {
            deposit(amount);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

WithdrawThread.java

```
public class WithdrawThread implements Runnable {

    private Account account;
    private double amount;

    public WithdrawThread(Account account, double amount) {
        // Set the account & balance
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount) throws InterruptedException {
        double bal = account.getBalance();
        if (amount > bal) {
            wait();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong amount!");
        }

        bal -= amount;
        account.setBalance(bal);
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Withdraw " + amount + " new balance in thread number " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + " balance is " + bal);
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // make a withdrawal
        try {
            withdraw(amount);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}// end WithdrawThread class
```

InternetBankingSystem.java

```
public class InternetBankingSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account accountObject = new Account(100);

        new Thread(new DepositThread(accountObject, 30)).start();
        new Thread(new DepositThread(accountObject, 20)).start();
        new Thread(new DepositThread(accountObject, 10)).start();

        new Thread(new WithdrawThread(accountObject, 30)).start();
        new Thread(new WithdrawThread(accountObject, 50)).start();
        new Thread(new WithdrawThread(accountObject, 20)).start();
    } // end main()
}
```

There is an output:
[image: incorrect output for withdraw]

Comment: *Always* call wait() in a loop based on the condition you're checking for, as [described in the method's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--).

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding the use of `synchronized`. This keyword operates in the *instance* object that you're running in.

Right now, you're putting the `synchronized` keyword on the `run` method of `DepositThread` and `WithdrawThread`. Then you create multiple instances. So each of these instances is completely independent, and the synchronized keyword only "locks" the particular DepositThread or WithdrawThread that you're running at the moment.
So effectively, you're not synchronizing at all.

You're also modeling this in a non-object oriented fashion. You should move the `withdraw` and `deposit` methods into the `Account` class, and make these methods `synchronized`.

Here's how you could do that in the `Account` class:

<sub>(note that your wait/notify usage don't make any sense. I've left them in, but why would you not be able to deposit when the balance is below zero, and even if that were the business rule, why would you then wait for a notify from the withdraw method? Because the withdraw method will never make the balance higher than what it already was)</sub>

```
public class Account {

    private double balance = 0;

    public Account(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(double amount) throws InterruptedException {
        double bal = getBalance();
        if (amount <= 0) {
            wait();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't not deposit!");
        }

        bal += amount;
        this.balance = bal;
        System.out.println("Deposit " + amount + " new balance in thread number " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + " balance is " + bal);
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(double amount) throws InterruptedException {
        double bal = getBalance();
        if (amount > bal) {
            wait();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong amount!");
        }

        bal -= amount;
        this.balance = bal;
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Withdraw " + amount + " new balance in thread number " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + " balance is " + bal);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm, so where synchronized belong? in which class?

Comment: I've added code to my answer that should make this clear.

Comment: Ok, so I used your Account class, and adjusted classes                                                                                               `public class WithdrawThread implements Runnable {

private Account account;

private double amount;

public WithdrawThread(Account account, double amount) {

// Set the account & balance

this.account = account;

this.amount = amount;



}

public void run() {
try {

account.withdraw(amount);


} catch (InterruptedException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}

}}//end Wit`